# How to indent JSON using DefaultPrettyPrinter?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson

Take a look at the code and please suggest me how should it be implemented to get the required JSON format

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
DefaultPrettyPrinter printer = new DefaultPrettyPrinter()
                    .withObjectIndenter(new DefaultIndenter("  ","\n"));

String result= mapper.writer(printer).writeValueAsString(getnames()); // getnames()-> returns a list of Objects
```

This produces JSON of the format,

```
[ {
  "test" : "Siva"
}, {
  "test" : "Duke"
} ]
```

This is not the format I require.

**Required:**

```
[{
  "test": "Siva"
},{
  "test": "Duke"
}]
```

What all needs to be formatted when compared to the current response?

```
[{   // No space between [{
  "test": "Nukem"   // 2 space before "test" & No space before : & 1 space before "Nukem"
},{   // and no space between },{
  "test": "Duke"
}]
```

Comment: You can use Gson. https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-enable-pretty-print-json-output-gson/
And can you tell, why there is such a requirement to control spaces after and before colon? For this much granular formatting, you may have to write your own formatter, i fear

Comment: Why do you require that format? For JSON parsers, that whitespace is (or should be) irrelevant.

Comment: True...its irrelevant... I just want to how we create custom formatter.Thats all.